# Applying to_datetime to all columns except index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that has an index (uid) and 9 variables that are dates currently as strings.

I managed to convert them to date time with `pd.to_datetime`, however I want to do this to all columnns without writing the command for all columns one by one like this:

```
initData['invited'] = pd.to_datetime(initData['invited'], dayfirst = True)
initData['sign_up'] = pd.to_datetime(initData['sign_up'], dayfirst = True)
initData['card_activated'] = pd.to_datetime(initData['card_activated'], dayfirst = True)
```

How can I do this more elegant? I tried the `.apply` but I get an error because it tries to convert the dataframe index to datetime too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
initData = initData.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
#same as
#initData = initData.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst = True))
```

Sample:

```
initData = pd.DataFrame({'A':['01-01-2017','02-01-2017','03-01-2017'],
                   'B':['05-01-2017','06-01-2017','07-01-2017'],
                   'C':['01-01-2017','02-01-2017','03-01-2017']})

print (initData)
            A           B           C
0  01-01-2017  05-01-2017  01-01-2017
1  02-01-2017  06-01-2017  02-01-2017
2  03-01-2017  07-01-2017  03-01-2017

initData = initData.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

print (initData)
           A          B          C
0 2017-01-01 2017-01-05 2017-01-01
1 2017-01-02 2017-01-06 2017-01-02
2 2017-01-03 2017-01-07 2017-01-03

print (initData.dtypes)
A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
C    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```